# Parsing "1.5" with AllowDecimalPoint gives FormatException

Tags: c#, parsing, .net-core, double, c#-interactive

When I try to run this code using the C# Interactive Compiler

```cs
double.Parse("1.5", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
```

I've this exception

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
  + System.Number.ParseDouble(string, System.Globalization.NumberStyles, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo)
  + double.Parse(string, System.Globalization.NumberStyles)
  + <Initialize>.MoveNext()
```

I've read this from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=netcore-3.1) but I don't get wiser from it.

> Indicates that the numeric string can have a decimal point. If the `NumberStyles` value includes the `AllowCurrencySymbol` flag and the parsed string includes a currency symbol, the decimal separator character is determined by the `CurrencyDecimalSeparator` property. Otherwise, the decimal separator character is determined by the `NumberDecimalSeparator` property.

Also code below gives me the same error:

```cs
double.Parse("1.500", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
```

Why I've this error? I expected that it gives me 1.5 as a double because decimal point is allowed.

**Side note:** My computer is configured to use a comma as a decimal separator meaning that code below works.

```cs
double.Parse("1,5", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
```

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question in side note? decimal point actually means decimal separator, which is comma in your current culture. You have to use `double.Parse("1.5", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a third parameter to the call

```
double.Parse("1.5", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This happens because your locale settings doesn't accept a point as decimal separator, so you need to add that parameter to explain that you are parsing a number where the decimal separator is a point.